# How can I get my XML debugging extension to be recognized by the system?

Tags: xml, debugging

When I try to run a simple XML file, it says "You don't have an extension for debugging XML. Should we find a XML extension in the Marketplace?" with a button that says Find XML Extension. XML Tools is installed. I turned the computer off and on again. Same thing.

Here are the [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBeib.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9FTh.png)

Any ideas how I can get out of this loop?

I went to ChatGPT and did these

Check extension activation: Open the Extensions view in Visual Studio Code and ensure that the XML Tools extension is listed and enabled. If it is not enabled, click on the "Enable" button next to the extension.

Verify XML file association: Make sure that XML files are associated with the XML Tools extension. Right-click on an XML file in the Explorer pane of Visual Studio Code, select "Open With", and check if XML Tools is the selected default program. If not, choose XML Tools as the default program for XML files.

Test with a different XML file: Try opening and editing a different XML file in Visual Studio Code to see if the issue persists. It's possible that the particular XML file you are working with has specific characteristics or issues that affect the XML Tools extension's behavior.

Update Visual Studio Code and extensions: Ensure that you have the latest version of Visual Studio Code and all installed extensions, including XML Tools. Go to the Extensions view, click on the gear icon in the top-right corner, and select "Check for Extension Updates". Also, check for updates in the Visual Studio Code application itself by going to the Help menu and selecting "Check for Updates".

Reinstall XML Tools extension: Uninstall the XML Tools extension, restart Visual Studio Code, and then reinstall the extension. This can help resolve any potential installation issues.

I did not try this yet:

Disable other extensions: Temporarily disable other extensions that may be interfering with the XML Tools extension. Some extensions might conflict with XML Tools or override its functionality. Disable extensions related to XML, debugging, or any other extensions that might affect XML editing. Then, check if the issue still occurs.

Comment: See following : https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2022/11/29/new-vscode-xml-extension-improves-developer-experience#